# excel rolling 6 month calculation

Tags: excel, sum, average, formula, offset

I have a row with 12 columns, one for each month, and each column has scores for each item I am tracking.

What I am trying to do is to get a rolling sum of the 3 last months and 6 months, but the problem is that the formula seems to retract 6 columns even if only data for Jan is on file.

This is a problem since in the columns before the monthly data I have various numbers that now get absorbed into the sum calculation.

Picture below for your reference. Thanks.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5hKv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some If()s

For Q (3month)

```
    =SUM(OFFSET(E2;0;COUNT(E2:P2)-IF(COUNT(E2:P2)>3;3;COUNT(E2:P2));1;IF(COUNT(E2:P2)>3;3;COUNT(E2:P2))))
```

and for R (6month)

```
    =SUM(OFFSET(E2;0;COUNT(E2:P2)-IF(COUNT(E2:P2)>6;6;COUNT(E2:P2));1;IF(COUNT(E2:P2)>6;6;COUNT(E2:P2))))
```

Should work

Comment: question, how can I modify this to ignore "0" columns? I have formulas in each cell and they return "0" (not empty cell) if there is no record on file, which messes with the rolling statistic.